# Run php script exactly every second?

Tags: php, linux

I need to run php script every second regardless of how long it will run.
Tried to do it that way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import threading, time, os

def f():
    os.system('php /var/www/test/artisan time:server > /dev/null &')
    threading.Timer(1, f).start()

f()
```

but php script is executed with unequal intervals. A little more or a little less than one second. Prompt how correctly to make the intervals of exactly one second? Not necessarily with python.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Cron jobs dont support second intervals I don't think

Comment: unfortunately, minimum cron interval is 1 minute

Comment: Thanks @iJamesPHP I had forgotten that

Comment: You could write a simple daemon to do this

Comment: It would be a simple linux service shell script

Comment: @iJamesPHP I'm fairly certain that this is what this python script is doing already....

Comment: The script is has python as the interpreter but the question is about php. Please decide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
set_time_limit(60);
$start = time();

for ($i = 0; $i <= 59; ++$i) {
    // Do whatever you want here
    time_sleep_until($start + $i + 1);
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. In my case I had to add the "59" inclusive ($i <= 59) and it works fine.

Comment: @ErnestFaizullin Thank you
I have updated the code as per your findings

Comment: I'd note that if "Do whatever you want here" takes longer than a second at times, some seconds will be skipped.

Comment: @ceejayoz Any more detailed explanation would be more helpful. Thanks

Comment: @A.A Consider what your code will do if "do whatever you want here" is `sleep(10)`. (In the real world, this might be a slow-running API call, for example.)

Answer (score 1):

The script finishing execution in exactly one second intervals, as in 1000000μs, is going to be nearly impossible to achieve just because of how processing works.

This would require:

1. A process that spawns exactly every 1000000μs
2. A CPU always available to accept the runnable process (no other load)
3. A process that always takes the same amount of time to execute

You may be able to acheive one or two of these, but all three aren't realistic.  Number 3 is going to be the main issue.